# how can i draw a tree hierarchy using JUNG?

Tags: java, layout, tree, graph, jung

I'm new to [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net). I tried to draw a graph of a tree using the TreeLayout but the tree never comes out like a real tree. Every time the tree looks different. How can I make the tree look like a normal tree with the root on top & the rest of the nodes descending from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to Initialize the `TreeLayout` after adding the Vertexes to the graph, I tried that and it worked for me.

You have to do something like the following: (please note that this is a 1 year old code that i had, you might find it to be a little out dated)

```
Layout<GraphVertex, GraphEdge> layout; //create a layout
layout = new TreeLayout<GraphVertex, GraphEdge>((Forest<GraphVertex, GraphEdge>) g); 
// initialize your layout using the graph you created, which has to be of type forest
vv.setGraphLayout(layout); 
// set the layout of the visualization viewer you are using to be the layout you just created (the tree layout)
```

`GraphVertex` Is the class which represents a vertex in the graph, `GraphEdge` represents the edges in your graph.

Comment: and what would be the data type of the variable g in your example code? (I used SparseGraph and the runtime error is that the SparseGraph cannot be cast to edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Forest)

Comment: @bikashg It should be something that implements the [Forest](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Forest.html) interface, like these: DelegateForest, DelegateTree, OrderedKAryTree (from the documentation), In my case I had my own implementation of Forest interface.